# What is the parameter in theme to change the color of the Camera Frame

Tags: 3d-view, theme

I'd like to change the frame color when looking through the camera viewport both when locked and unlocked -  is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that's just the colour of any selected or active object in Blender so if you change that you change the lot!

Comment: The orange frame when the camera is selected is the _Active Object_ color, so changing it for the camera will change it for other objects as well. But I haven't found out which is the yellow color displaying the field of view or whatever.